# ¿Como optimizar este codigo para leer bases de datos nuy grandes?

Tags: base-de-datos, r, rstudio

```
setwd("C:/Users/Neo/Desktop")

tabla <- read.csv("220814COVID19MEXICO.csv",header = T)

datos <- subset(tabla,tabla$CLASIFICACION_FINAL == 3 & tabla$ENTIDAD_RES == 18)

write.csv(datos,file="covid2022.csv")
```

ayer intentaba crear un codigo para poder filtrar una base de datos del covid y resulta que funciona pero la computadora estaba muriendose en el proceso alguna forma eficiente de mejorar este proceso?

Comment: Bienvenido NeoGeoMax a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: El código que muestras es de lo más básico y simple, no tiene mucha forma de optimizarse. Tendrías que identificar dónde esta el cuello de botella: lectura del csv, filtrado de los datos, o escritura del csv.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes testear con el paquete `data.table`, `fread` y `fwrite` en general funcionan mucho más rápido.

```
library(data.table)
tabla <- fread("220814COVID19MEXICO.csv")

datos <- tabla[CLASIFICACION_FINAL == 3 & ENTIDAD_RES == 18]

fwrite(datos, file="covid2022.csv")
```